# PHP, is possible add/use a INDEX in QUERY {DESCRIBE/SHOW FIELDS}?

Tags: php, mysql

we want use:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

then when we run the simple QUERY ("PERFECT" QUERY?)

```
DESCRIBE `table`;
```

or

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM `table`;
```

or

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'root_logs_todos' AND TABLE_NAME = 'logs_ipsfreq';
```

in any case we obtain:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No index used in query/prepared statement {QUERY}

is this a bug from PHP ? (we use the current PHP 8!)
is this a bug from MYSQL? (https://www.oracle.com/search/results?cat=mysql&Ntk=SI-ALL5&Ntt=MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)

we not want disable "EXTREM" **mysqli_report()** using the modes

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
```

or

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

some idea please?

Comment: PMA - PhpMyAdmin also show a warning: `Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.` (surely they disable report WARNINGS with **mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);**

Comment: where/when **DUPLICATED**? show me ONE Q about the same point: `is possible add/use a INDEX in QUERY {DESCRIBE/SHOW FIELDS}? `, please read before of  eliminate, block, close a post